# How can I cut a pdf and create galleries of photo in python

Tags: python, pdf, photo-gallery

I have a pdf with image like the one that I will show below, I would like to create a pdf with galleries instead of the entire photo with number, so including only the images with the same dimension.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWoe9.png)

Comment: Hmm, ok so you want to rip the images out of the PDF and then create a gallery of them?

Comment: @MrMatthewKevinHutchins Yes, This would be fine too. I have no idea of how to do that so I was not able to formulate the correct question maybe. I would like to have only the image without the scale on the y and x axis

Comment: Oh, so you want to rip the images and then crop them to hide the x and y axis I see, that’s not too hard. And the images are all the same size?

Comment: @MrMatthewKevinHutchins Yes, exacly

Comment: Ok, sorry took me a bit, was driving all day, hope this helps, code needs tweaking for how you want to crop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install this into your python

pip install PyMuPDF Pillow

pip install fpdf

After this we extract the images with the below code.

```
import fitz # PyMuPDF
import io
from PIL import Image
# file path you want to extract images from
file = "1710.05006.pdf"
# open the file
pdf_file = fitz.open(file)
# iterate over PDF pages
for page_index in range(len(pdf_file)):
  # get the page itself
  page = pdf_file[page_index]
  image_list = page.getImageList()
  # printing number of images found in this page
  if image_list:
    print(f"[+] Found a total of {len(image_list)} images in page {page_index}")
  else:
      print("[!] No images found on page", page_index)
  for image_index, img in enumerate(page.getImageList(), start=1):
    # get the XREF of the image
    xref = img[0]
    # extract the image bytes
    base_image = pdf_file.extractImage(xref)
    image_bytes = base_image["image"]
    # get the image extension
    image_ext = base_image["ext"]
    # load it to PIL
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
    # save it to local disk
    image.save(open(f"image{page_index+1}_{image_index}.{image_ext}", "wb"))
```

After this we need to crop the images

```
from PIL import Image
import os.path, sys

path = "C:\\Users\\xie\\Desktop\\tiff\\Bmp"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

def crop():
    for item in dirs:
        fullpath = os.path.join(path,item)         #corrected
         if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
            im = Image.open(fullpath)
             f, e = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
             imCrop = im.crop((30, 10, 1024, 1004)) #corrected
             imCrop.save(f + 'Cropped.bmp', "BMP", quality=100)

crop()
```

After this compile back into PDF

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF()
dims = [
    (x, y,w,h),
    (x, y,w,h),
    (x, y,w,h),
    (x, y,w,h)
]

for image_type in set([i[0] for i in image_list]):
    imgs = list(filter(lambda x:image_type in x,image_list))
    pdf.add_page()
    for i,j in zip(imgs,dims):
        pdf.image(i,j[0],j[1],j[2],j[3])
pdf.output("yourfile.pdf", "F")
```